# placeholders when generating web pages

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, placeholder

I have seen web templates which include {title} {body} {name} {address} etc. all through it and then when it generates the page these are replaced with information from a MySQL call.

I am looking to do something similar and wondering if this is built into one of the web languages i.e. HTML, Javascript, PHP etc. or have they built their own scripts to replace this when generating the page?

I don't mind writing my own scripts to do this, just wondering if something already existed which does this.

Comment: It seems like you are finding for templating engine...

Comment: There are plenty of things that do this with PHP (for instance) - I always thought PHPTAL (http://phptal.org/) looked promising but I'm not sure whether it's still being supported. This question will probably be closed as being *too broad* however.

Comment: Sounds like I need to do something like a stringReplace.

Comment: That's pretty much the simplest RYO solution, yeah.

Comment: Commonly used one is Smarty ( http://www.smarty.net/ ) but I found it bulky ( too much unnecessary logic ) - and besides - PHP is in its own right a MARVELLOUS templating engine, why use (probable) regular expressions to search for {my_var} when <?php print($my_var); ?> will suffice? It just added overhead. 

The old "Separation of code from template" shouldn't matter - there will still be some sort of tag to replace, it may as well be pure PHP. Just keep your application logic out of the HTML templates and it will be fine for designers to work on!